# Properties of a dynamical system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Can you please help me to prove these properties of the given dynamical system?
$$\begin{align}
\frac{dN}{dt}=&aN\left(1-\frac{N}{k}\right)-bNP\\
\frac{dP}{dt}=&cNP-DP\\\text{so that:}\\
N(0)\geq& 0\\P(0)\geq& 0
\end{align}$$

1. Prove that $R^+$ is positive invariant set for the system.$\\$
2. Prove that the system is dissipative.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are $a, k, b, c$ and $D$ constants? If yes, according to your definition of dissipative system, do you need to find a function $V(N,P)$ such that $\frac{d}{dt} \, V(N,P) < 0$?

Comment: And you have really no idea about how to attack even one part of this? How comes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $a,k,b,c$ and $D$ are positive constants, the system can be written as
\begin{align}
\frac{dN}{dt} &= \big(a - \frac{a}{k} \, N - b\, P\big)\, N \\
\frac{dP}{dt} &= \big(c\, N - D \big)\, P
\end{align}
Observe that if you take a solution $N(t)$ of the equation
$$\frac{dN}{dt} = a\, N - \frac{a}{k} \, N^2$$ then a direct check shows that 
$(N(t), 0)$ is a solution of the original system 
\begin{align}
\frac{dN}{dt} &= \big(a - \frac{a}{k} \, N - b\, P\big)\, N \\
\frac{dP}{dt} &= \big(c\, N - D \big)\, P
\end{align} which means that the line $\{(N,P) \, : \, P=0 \}$ is invariant under the flow, i.e. it is a trajectory of the system (the unstable manifold of the equilibrium $(0,0)$). Analogously, if one takes a solution $P(t)$ of the equation
$$\frac{dP}{dt} = D\, P$$ then a direct check shows that $(0,P(t))$ is a solution to the original system. In other words, the line $\{(N,P) \, : \, N=0 \}$ is invariant under the flow, i.e. it is a trajectory of the system (the stable manifold of the equilibrium $(0,0)$). Thus, if a solution $(N(t), P(t))$ of the original system, starting from the positive quadrant, i.e. $(N(0), P(0)) \in \mathbb{R}_+^2$, traverses a trajectory for $t \in \mathbb{R}$ that always stays in  $\mathbb{R}_+^2= \{(N,P) \, : \, N>0,\, P>0\}$ because in order to leave $\mathbb{R}_+^2$ that trajectory needs to intersect one of the trajectories lying on either $\{(N,P) \, : \, P=0 \}$ or $\{(N,P) \, : \, N=0 \}$ which is impossible because two different trajectories of an autonomous system like the given one do not intersect. Therefore, $\mathbb{R}_+^2 $ is an invariant domain of the system.

For the second question, I assume you have to manufacture a function $V(N,P)$ in $\mathbb{R}_+^2$ with the property that $\frac{d}{dt} V(N,P) \leq 0$. In order to do that, first calculate the equilibrium points of the original system
\begin{align}
\frac{dN}{dt} &= a\, N - \frac{a}{k} \, N^2 - b\, NP \\
\frac{dP}{dt} &= c\, NP - D\, P 
\end{align}
i.e. solve the equations
\begin{align}
0 &= a\, N - \frac{a}{k} \, N^2 - b\, NP = \big( a\, - \frac{a}{k} \, N - b\, P\big)\, N \\
0 &= c\, NP - D\, P  =  \big(c\, N - D\big)\, P
\end{align}
If $N=0$ then $P=0$ too. Assume $N \neq 0$. Then either $P=0$ and in this case $N = k$ or 
$$N= \frac{D}{c} \,\,\text{ and } \,\, P = \frac{a}{b} - \frac{aD}{bck}$$ which is located in $\mathbb{R}^2_+$ if and only if $ck > D$. The only equilibrium in the interior of $\mathbb{R}^2_+$ is $\Big( \frac{D}{c}, \,  \frac{a}{b} - \frac{aD}{bck}\Big)$. Now, rewrite your system in the form
\begin{align}
\frac{dN}{dt} &= a\, N - \frac{aD}{ck} \, N - b\, NP + \frac{aD}{ck} \, N - \frac{a}{k} \, N^2\\
\frac{dP}{dt} &= c\, NP - D\, P 
\end{align}
I claim that the closely related system (in fact a truncated system, obtained from the latter one by removing the last two terms from the first equation)
\begin{align}
\frac{dN}{dt} &= a\, N - \frac{aD}{ck} \, N - b\, NP\\
\frac{dP}{dt} &= c\, NP - D\, P 
\end{align}
is integrable, i.e. it is conservative because it has a conserved a quantity, i.e. a first integral of motion. Rewrite the system as
\begin{align}
\frac{dN}{\left(\, a\, N - \frac{aD}{ck} \, N - b\, NP \, \right)} &= dt\\
\frac{dP}{\left( c\, NP - D\, P \right)} &= dt
\end{align} which after eliminating the $dt$ from both equations reduces to
\begin{align}
\frac{dN}{\left(\, a\, N - \frac{aD}{ck} \, N - b\, NP \, \right)} = 
\frac{dP}{\left( c\, NP - D\, P \right)}
\end{align} which can be represented also as
\begin{align}
\frac{dN}{\left(\, a - \frac{aD}{ck} - b\, P \, \right) N} = 
\frac{dP}{\left( c\, N - D\, \right) P}
\end{align} After reorganizing the terms of this latter differential form gets
\begin{align}
\frac{ \left( c\, N - D\, \right) \, dN}{N} = 
\frac{ \left(\, a - \frac{aD}{ck} - b\, P \, \right) \, dP}{ P}
\end{align} which is exact, i.e. is the differential of a function i.e. there exists $V(N,P)$ such that
\begin{align}
dV &= \frac{ \left( c\, N - D\, \right) \, dN}{N} - \frac{ \left(\, a - \frac{aD}{ck} - b\, P \, \right) \, dP}{ P} = \left( c - \frac{D}{N}\right) \, dN - { \left(\, \Big(a - \frac{aD}{ck}\Big) \frac{1}{P} - b \, \right) \, dP} 
\end{align} which after integration turns into 
$$V(N,P) = c\, N - D \, \log(N) + b\, P - \Big(a - \frac{aD}{ck}\Big) \, \log(P) + V_0 $$ where the constant $V_0$ is chosen so that the value of the function $V(N,P)$ at the equilibrium point $\Big( \frac{D}{c}, \,  \frac{a}{b} - \frac{aD}{bck}\Big)$ is zero. Also the value of the differential $dV$ et the equilibrium point is $\Big( \frac{D}{c}, \,  \frac{a}{b} - \frac{aD}{bck}\Big)$ by construction, so the function $V$ has a critical point at this equilibrium. If you calculate the matrix of the second derivatives of $V$ at that equilibrium, you see that the matrix is diagonal with positive entries, so positive definite, which means the equilibrium is a minimum of the function $V$, i.e. the minimum energy of the modified conservative system occurs at the equilibrium.

Now, take a solution $(N(t), P(t))$ in $\mathbb{R}^2_+$ of the original system and calculate 
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt} \, V\big(N(t), P(t)\big) &= \left( c - \frac{D}{N}\right) \, \frac{dN}{dt} - { \left(\, \Big(a - \frac{aD}{ck}\Big) \frac{1}{P} - b \, \right) \, \frac{dP}{dt}}\\
& = \left( c - \frac{D}{N}\right) \,\left( a\, N - \frac{a}{k} \, N^2 - b\, NP\right) - { \left(\, \Big(a - \frac{aD}{ck}\Big) \frac{1}{P} - b \, \right) \, \left(c\, NP - D\, P\right) }\\
&= - \frac{a}{ck}\big(c\, N - D\big)^2 \leq 0
\end{align} which means that $V$ is a global Lyapunov (kind of like an energy) function for your system in the domain $\mathbb{R}^2$, the equilibrium point there is asymptotically stable, and the system itselfis dissipative  in the first quadrant.

Comment: thanks a lot for the solution!

Comment: @КсенияЦочева  Няма защо :)... Все пак имай впредвид, че решението зависи и от определенията за дисипативни системи които са ви дали на лекции, така, че не съм сигурен дали се търси решение точно в този вид. Но това е един възможен подход. По принцип, на тази система лесно се изследва фазовия портрет, особено ако се разгледат правата по които векторното поле е хоризонтално насочено и правата по която полето е вертикално насочено.